# continuous embedding in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $(\Omega,M,\mu)$ be a complete measure space.

Is it true that $L^1(Ω,M,μ) ∩ L^∞(Ω,M,μ)$ is continuously embedded in $L^p(Ω,M,μ)$ for all $p∈[1,∞]$?

I think yes:

Let $I\colon X \to Y$, $Ix = x$ where $X = L^1(Ω,M,μ) ∩ L^∞(Ω,M,μ)$, $Y = L^p(Ω,M,μ)$ for any $p$.

I have to prove that $I$ is bounded and this is trivial thanks to the inequality

$$‖‖_ ⩽ (μ(Ω))^{1/p}  ‖‖_∞$$

Am I missing something?

Comment: What if $\mu(\Omega)=\infty$?

Comment: yes, of course in the assumption that this is finite. Or there is a more general way to prove this?

Comment: You have to specify a norm for $X$.

Comment: i have used the L∞ norm for the X space

Comment: The "correct" norm on $X$ to get a continuous embedding would be something like $\max\{\|\cdot\|_1,\|\cdot\|_\infty\}$ (there are many equivalent versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the real line with Lebesgue measure let $f_n=\frac 1 n \chi_{(n,n+n^2)}$. Then $f_n \in L^{1}\cap L^{\infty}$ and $f_n \to 0$ in $L^{\infty}$ norm.  But $f_n$ does not converge in $L^{2}$. So your map is not continuous when  $X$ is given $\|f\|_{\infty}$ norm.

Comment: and if i consider the norm of X as the product of norm 1 and ∞ and apply the interpolation inequality ? more precisely this inequality : |||| ≤ (||||1)^1/ * (||||∞)^1−1/ 
In this case even the hp of Ω finite is not necessary

Comment: Product of two norms is not a norm.  @maru0032